# Most number of equilateral triangles formed by 13 points

Tags: geometry, combinatorics

What is the most number of equilateral triangles you can form by drawing 13 points on a piece of paper? Each triangle must have 3 equal sides and pass through 3 points. Only equilateral triangles can be counted, while other triangles must be ignored. Triangles can be of different size.

Comment: "pass through 3 points": so they don't have to be the triangle's vertices?

Comment: no the points are the vertices of the triangle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have arranged for a total of...

> $14+7+5+3=29$ triangles
>  (edge lengths $1,\sqrt{3},2,\sqrt{7}$)
>  [image]

Comment: Oooh very nice! This could be our winner. Let's wait and see if anyone can beat it.

Comment: If you restrict to a triangular grid with 10 points per side, 29 is optimal.

Comment: @RobPratt how did you prove this?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky, I used integer linear programming with a binary decision variable $x_i$ for each of the $\binom{n+1}{2}$ nodes and a binary decision variable $y_t$ for each equilateral triangle.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_t y_t$ subject to $\sum_i x_i = 13$ and $y_t \le x_i$ if node $i$ is a vertex of triangle $t$.

Comment: What is the $\binom{n+1}{2}$? @RobPratt

Comment: @justhalf, it's the $n$th triangular number, the number of points in a triangular grid with base $n$.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the search space is the full triangle with side length 10, then you search for a subset of nodes, by using all possible triangles as the constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an attempt for

> 28

equilateral triangles:

> [image]
>
>  12 of size 1
>  8 of size $\sqrt3$, 6 using the central point and two of the outermost points, and 2 with the central point in the middle (thanks @hexomino and @DmitryKamenetsky)
>  6 of size 2
>  2 of size 3

Comment: This was the solution I had in mind.

Comment: I believe there are two more sqrt(3) triangles - they have the central point in their centre.

Answer (score 4):

My attempt:

> [image]

There is

> $28$ Equilateral Triangles. (Can you spot all of them?)

Comment: I think there are more triangles. Have you counted all the sqrt(3) triangles? See the other answer.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky That's the 6 in the list (3 in each orientation). The final 2 is for the sqrt(7) triangles.